# Inherited PHP site not finding assets

Tags: php, redirect, webserver

I've inherited a PHP site from another developer and can't quite figure out what's going wrong. I'm suspecting some kind of rewrite rule somewhere but Im not sure where to look (or what specifically to look for...)

I've installed MAMP and it is working fine. I've got a couple sites running in the MAMP directory with no problems.

When I drop this site in and try to run the pages, I get pages with no CSS, JavaSCript or images. When I 'right-click' an image and open it in a new tab the image can't be found because the browser tries to go up one level in the directory to the MAMP directory in stead of looking in the site root directory.

Same thing on links to other pages, they all try to go up to the MAMP htdocs directory.

For example in htdocs I have the root folder of my site with the index page: 'htdocs/mysite.com/index.php'

On the page is a link to another page `<li class="nav_company"><a href="/company/index.php" title="Company">Company</a>`

Clicking on 'Company' causes the browser to go up to the htdocs folder and look for the '/company/index.php', which of course doesn't exist.

Where do I go looking for the culprit on this? Is there a term or something I can search the site files for? I'm using dreamweaver and cold utilize the find and replace tool if I just knew what to go looking for...

*Edit* Here's the (sanitized) .htaccess file in the root folder of the site

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

Redirect 301 /products/ http://www.sitename.com/plastic-handles/
Redirect 301 /plastic/index.html http://www.sitename.com/plastic/plastic.html
Redirect 301 /applicator/index.html http://www.sitename.com/applicator/applicators.html
Redirect 301 /company/index.html http://www.sitename.com/company/about-us.html
Redirect 301 /contact/index.html http://www.sitename.com/contact/contact-us.html
Redirect 301 /news/index.html http://www.sitename.com/news/news.html
Redirect 301 /trade/index.html http://www.sitename.com/trade/tradeshows.html
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for a `.htaccess` file, which is a hidden file when viewing in most file browsers.

Comment: Found the .htaccess file and included it in the post for review.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your assets and links are all pointing to the root so /contact/index.php will look at `http://localhost/contact/index.php` instead of `http://localhost/mysite.com/contact/index.php`

Look into setting up a virtual host to point to the new sites directory.

Otherwise it would be a case of changing all the links and assets to the full URL e.g. `http://localhost/mysite.com/contact/index.php`

Hope this helps

Edit: here is a guide to setting up a virtual host http://sawmac.com/mamp/virtual/

Edit 2: in response to your edit, .htaccess isn't going to make a difference as when you click a link or the server looks for an asset it's going to be looking in htdocs/. It will go no further and therefore will not reach your .htaccess.